# I have JSON Structure in POJO and Dynamic data in HashMap I want to set the data from Hashmap to POJO to send the payload, How Can I achieve that?

Tags: java, json, hashmap, pojo, rest-assured

I have JSON Structure in POJO and dynamic data in HashMap. Now I want to set the data from Hashmap to POJO to send the payload in API, How Can I achieve that?

POJO Class:

```java
package pojo;

import java.util.List;

public class PostAccountCreateAPI {

    private String FirstName;
    private String LastName;
    private String PASSWORD;
    private List<Email> Email;

    public PostAccountCreateAPI() {}

    public PostAccountCreateAPI(String FirstName, String LastName, String PASSWORD, List<Email> Email) {
        this.FirstName = FirstName;
        this.LastName = LastName;
        this.PASSWORD = PASSWORD;
        this.Email = Email;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String FirstName) {
        this.FirstName = FirstName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return this.FirstName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String LastName) {
        this.LastName = LastName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return this.LastName;
    }

    public void setPASSWORD(String PASSWORD) {
        this.PASSWORD = PASSWORD;
    }

    public String getPASSWORD() {
        return this.PASSWORD;
    }

    public void setEmail(List<Email> Email) {
        this.Email = Email;
    }

    public List<Email> getEmail() {
        return this.Email;
    }
}
```

The Data is stored in a Hashmap as below:

```
{PASSWORD=p@$$word123, LASTNAME=LoUSj, FIRSTNAME=FSFBE, 
EMAIL_TYPE=Primary, VALUE=test7EZK0@mail7.io}
```

How can I assign the values from `Hashmap` to POJO directly to create API Payload?

Comment: Have you tried ```pojoObj.setPassword(dataMap.get("PASSWORD"));``` and similarly for other fields ?

Comment: Yes, I did that but I am searching for some other optimized way.

Comment: Make sure you [edit] your question if you have more specific requirements for an answer. When you said optimised do you mean performance or are you referring to 'optimising'the amount of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A constructor may be provided in the POJO to accept a map

```java
public PostAccountCreateAPI(Map<String, String> map) {
    this(
        map.get("FIRSTNAME"), map.get("LASTNAME"), 
        map.get("PASSWORD"), Arrays.asList(map.get("VALUE"))
    );
}
```

or some utility method:

```java
public class PojoBuilder {
    public static PostAccountCreateAPI create(Map<String, String> map) {
        return new PostAccountCreateAPI(
            map.get("FIRSTNAME"),
            map.get("LASTNAME"),
            map.get("PASSWORD"),
            Arrays.asList(map.get("VALUE"))
        );
    }
}
```

---

**Update**

If the keys in the map vary for different maps, the list (or array) of the keys needs to be provided to iterate on, then assuming that the list have all relevant keys in appropriate order:

```java
public static PostAccountCreateAPI create(Map<String, String> map, List<String> keys) {

    return new PostAccountCreateAPI(
        map.get(keys.get(0)), // key0 - firstName
        map.get(keys.get(1)), // key1 - lastName
        map.get(keys.get(2)), // key2 - password
        Arrays.asList(keys.get(3)) // key3 - email
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Alex. I will always get different key and Value in my hashmap, Hence Is there any way through which we can iterate over data in hashmap irrespective of its key and value? and set the values to POJO?

Comment: `Map` provides sets of its entries via `entrySet` and keys via `keySet` which can be iterated by, but `HashMap` does not guarantee the order.  If you're aware of the key names, a list of keys should be provided along with the map.

Comment: Considering the above example, Can you please illustrate how can we do that?

Comment: @ArpitaGarg, did you see the update in the answer?